# Python Selenium Find Exclusively object attributes

Tags: python, selenium

Assuming I have a page source that contain following:

```
    <input name="username" id="1" />
    <input name="username" id="1" type="button" />
    <input name="username" id="1" align="mid" />
    <input name="username" id="1" color="blue" />
```

How to find exclusively the first one? I just want those with 2 attributes only (@name = 'username' and @id = '1') and no other additional attributes. 
If I use
`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'username'][@id = '1']")`

this will yield all the above. Appreciate any help.

*Extra note:

1) There are several `<input name="username" id="1" />` in different forms in the same page source.

2) I used tag name input as an example, can be other tag names in case some may be wondering why same input in different forms.

Answer (score 0):

"driver.find_elements" will return all the elements that match in an array. "driver.find_element" return the first one. 
Try:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'username'][@id = '1']")
```

Given what is above I am not clear about what you mean by "WITHOUT the attribute 'type'".

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'username'][@id = '1']")[0]
```

Given your last comment I made the edit below.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'username'][@id = '1'][not(contains(@type, 'button'))]")
```

Comment: Hi Jortega, basically I just need to find the first line which does not have attribute type = 'button'. Problem is there may be several of them either in forms, selection, etc. Thats why I need to use "driver.find_elements"

Comment: Well I would prefer not to use
```driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name = 'username'][@id = '1']")[0]```
as you have to know the index position beforehand. My case I will not know where they are since the page source may sort differently. Imagine if the order was

```<input name="username" id="1" type="button" />```

```<input name="username" id="1" />```

Comment: @Jason see my latest update if the other answer does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not` operator.

Exception the `@type` attribute but with specific value.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[(@name = 'username' and @id = '1') and not(@type='button')]")
```

Or without the `@type` attributte:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[(@name = 'username' and @id = '1') and not(@type)]")
```

Comment: Hi frianH, is there syntax for 'not everything else'?

Comment: @Jason What you mean `not everything else` ?

Comment: It may be other attribute than type='submit' which I won't know unless i go through each line of the page source and it would be a hassle to add the long list of 'not' attributes. I just want tag names with 2 attributes (@name = 'username' and @id = '1') and no other additional attributes.

Comment: @Jason If you want achieve the `type` without anything value, just remove the value : `not(@type)`, see the updated answer.

Comment: I see, thanks for the tip. So far this is closest to what I'm looking for. It would be perfect if its not just attribute @type but ALL other attributes. I've updated the question with few more input lines to reflect this.

Comment: @Jason So far, sadly, I have never read a thread on how to find xpath with logic: **select a node that only has** `attribute A` **and** `attribute B`, at least for me. You must reject all the attributes you don't want using the `not` operator, and mention them one by one. In your case: `not(@type) and not(@align) ....etc`.

Comment: Yea I've googled for quite some time and could not find any solution. So thought I try my luck here and started this thread.